# Transformations to obtain a new equation.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Another question from my online course that I don't understand.

Describe how the graph of $y=-2f(3(x-1))-4$  can be obtained from the graph of $f(x) = x^4$.

I am not sure what the $f$ value is or how the first could be transformed from $f(x) = x^4.$
Any help would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is asking what do the various transformations of the function $f$ do. Reading from the inside out, we start with $x-1$, which will translate the graph to the right one unit. The $3(x-1)$ will correspond to a horizontal shrink by a factor of 3. The $2f(3(x-1))$ will correspond to a vertical stretch by a factor of 2, and the $-4$ will shift the graph down four units.

It might also be helpful to consider a couple of examples. When $x=2$, $f(x) = 16$, but $2f(3(x-1))=158$. You can try other values yourself with this Wolfram Alpha link, just change the value of $x$ and hit enter: [http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%283%28%28x%29-1%29%29^4-4](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=2%283%28%28x%29-1%29%29%5E4-4).

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I just have one query. You say that the -4 will move the graph down only one unit. Why is this?

Comment: That's a typo, sorry. It is down 4 units, I'll edit. I think I was glancing at the line above.

Comment: Oh okay! Just making sure :) Thank you very much for your help!